# Map application in scheme

Tags: dictionary, functional-programming, scheme

I am trying to understand procedure application and computation order in scheme.
I have the following code:

```
(map map (list map) (list (list list)) '(((a b c))))
```

I know that `map` should be applied in the following manner:

```
(map procedure list list ...)
```

If more than one list is given, then they must all be the same length. 
The result of the above line is:

```
(map map (list map) (list (list list)) '(((a b c))))
=> ((((a) (b) (c))))
```

Why? What is the order of computation here?
I tried to break the line, obviously I am missing something here:

```
(list map)
=> (#<Function map>)     ;list1
(list (list list))
=> ((#<Function list>))  ;list2
'(((a b c)))
=> (((a b c)))           ;list3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct use of map is:

```scm
(map proc-of-n-arity list1 ... listn)
```

Thus if you have one list your proc should take one argument. The evaluation order is not defined so the expression for `listn` can come before the evaluation of `map` (which evaluates to a procedure). You can test this by having arguments that does side effects and see that it usually is left to right or right to left.

Nested expression, as if `proc-of-n-arity` were a complex procedure call with its own expressions is evaluated before `map` is applied since it is needed to be evaluated before thus even if the order ir unknown we know it is a depth first evaluation.

So back to your strange expression:

```scm
(map map (list map) (list (list list)) '(((a b c))))
```

Here `map` evaluates to a procedure. It evaluates `map` as a procedure for it's first argument and it evaluates the rest of the expressions such that you get `(#<map>)` `((#<list>))` and of course `(((a b c)))`, all one element lists. Thus you should expect a one element list back with the result of:

```scm
(map map (list list) '((a b c)))
```

This evaluates both `map` as a procedures and the lists as `(#<list>)` and `((a b c))`. Since it is a one element list one would again expect a one element list back with the result of:

```scm
(map list '(a b c))
```

This evaluates `map` and `list` as procedures and the second argument as `(a b c)`. You'l get a list with 3 elements with the result of `list` with one of each, ie. `((a) (b) (c))`

Going back to the fact that this was one element in a `map` application we know `map` will make a list with it like `(((a) (b) (c)))` and it is the one element in the outer `map` which also gets to be in a list and thus `((((a) (b) (c))))` is the end result.

Know that this result can be done much easier with:

```scm
(list (list (map list (caar '(((a b c)))))))
```

## List argument length

Note that the restriction on the same length list is true for `map` in R5RS and R6RS, but SRFI-1 will stop at the shortest list. eg:

```scm
#!r6rs

(import (except (rnrs base) map)
        (only (srfi :1) map circular-list))

(map + '(1 2 3) (circular-list 2)) ; ==> (3 4 5)
```

[SRFI-1](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) will become a standard list library in R7RS Large.